# Describing all homomorphisms of $S_n$ into $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

> Describe all homomorphisms of $S_n$ into $S_3$, $n \geq 5$.

Somehow it is a bit unclear to me what describing means. However, I would say that describing is meant with respect to generators. We have $$S_n = \left\langle \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & \dots & n\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle$$ and $|S_3| = 6$. So theoretically there would be $36$ possible homomorphisms. But thats not really descriptive. In the former part of the exercise we've already proved that $\text{Aut}(S_3) \cong S_3$ but I do not really know if this helps.

Comment: Not all $36$ possibilities define a homomorphism. For instance, $(12)$ must be sent to $(1)$ or another transposition.

Comment: @Ihf Sorry, that is what I meant with theoretically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick here is to recall that the kernel of a group homomorphism is a normal subgroup.  If $\phi:S_n \rightarrow S_3$ is a group homomorphism, we must have $S_n / \ker(\phi) \cong \operatorname{Im}(\phi)$, were $\ker(\phi)$ is normal in $S_n$.

For $n \geq 5$, the only nontrivial normal subgroup of $S_n$ is $A_n$, and $S_n / A_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ (which *is* a subgroup of $S_3$, namely, a subgroup generated by a transposition, so a homomorphism $S_n \rightarrow S_3$ is possible).

Lastly, don't forget about the trivial homomorphisms  ;)

---

**P.S.** if you want to consider homomorphisms $S_4 \rightarrow S_3$, it's useful to know that $S_4$ also has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.  Given that $S_4 / \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ has the same order as $S_3$, there is a possibility of an additional (surjective) homomorphism.  Note that it suffices to check whether this quotient group is abelian.